# BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter missing from latest BLE.net Nuget package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am totally inexperienced in ios and xamarin, so i apologize if this is a foolish question.

I am following the examples for [BLE.net](https://github.com/nexussays/BLE.net) and I can't find BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter, which is just the starting point. In Visual Studio, I can see all the methods in nexus.protocols.ble, and it doesn't look like it's there:

[image]

Has the Nuget package changed? If so, how do I figure out what how to use it without sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the ble.net library. The `BluetoothLowEnergyAdapter` class is platform-specific and only available in the platform packages (i.e., [ble.net-android](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ble.net-android), [ble.net-ios](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ble.net-ios), [ble.net-uwp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ble.net-uwp)).

You'll want to reference the [ble.net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ble.net) package in library code and the relevant platform package in your app project(s).

If you have any suggestions for the [readme](https://github.com/nexussays/BLE.net) or package descriptions that would have clarified this for you, please do let me know!